# Спецификатор friend в g++

Tags: g++, c++

Почему при компиляции c mingw компилятор не видит функции, объявленные со спецификатором friend? Ошибка: такая-то функция was not declared in this scope. Может, какие флаги нужны?

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть, как Вы ее декларируете.

Comment: Текст в студию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
public:
    friend A function();
    void rotate(char g);
};

A function()
{
    cout << " text" << endl;
}

void A::rotate(char g)
{
    cout << g;
    function();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A s;
    s.rotate('A');

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка вываливалась когда A function(){ cout << " text" << endl; } стоит после void A::rotate(char g)... сейчас всё компилит